# Understanding the Basics of Subdomains with VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, subdomain, namecheap

I would like to make two subdomains for my site. To do so, I have created three VirtualHosts in my `default` file under sites-available (I am using Apache on Ubuntu):

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
     ServerName nmagerko.me
     ...
     DocumentRoot /var/www
     ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
     ServerName sub1.nmagerko.me
     ...
     DocumentRoot /some/different/path
     ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
     ServerName sub2.nmagerko.me
     ...
     DocumentRoot /some/different/path2
     ...
</VirtualHost>
```

However, I am not sure of what to do after this point. I have each of these subdomains and my primary domain in my `/etc/hosts` file as `127.0.0.1` and I have set A Records for `sub1` and `sub2` in my domain registrar's domain editor. However, these A Records point to the same IP as my primary domain, since this is all being hosted on one system... which isn't very useful. So, when I go to `sub1.nmagerko.me` in my browser, I receive the same site as I would have as if I went to `nmagerko.me`.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, the config you wrote seem correct to me, so I will try to show you how to debug the problem:

1- Make sure that DNS is correctly configured executing `dig nmagerko.me`, `dig sub1.nmagerko.me` and `dig sub2.nmagerko.me` and looking for the IP. Use `wget X.nmagerko.me` to tests, browser could be caching DNS replies.

2- Make sure that files in `/some/different/path`, `/var/www` and `/some/different/pat2` are different.

3- Make sure you restart apache with

> sudo service apache2 restart

Beside, you can take a look at logs too.

Hope this help.

Comment: Well, when I executed `wget sub1.nmagerko.me` I got a 404, even though the DNS appeared to be configured correctly.

Comment: What about `wget nmagerko.me`? You said in the question "when I go to sub1.nmagerko.me in my browser, I receive the same site as I would have as if I went to nmagerko.me." Do you have an index.html or an index.php file in the path pointed by `sub1.nmagerko.me` *DocumentRoot*? I mean, exist  `/some/different/path/index.html` ?

Comment: Yes so nmagerko.me is currently a 404 (on purpose). However, sub1 and sub2 (these are just example subdomains) also give the 404 of the primary site. Instead, they should provide a different page for each.

Comment: Could you put here what apache log said when you make a requests? Execute  `tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log` and `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` and then the three wget commands and you will see in logs where apache is looking for the files, if in the same directory or not.

Comment: From Apache's access.log, I get `Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dumy connection) and from error.log, I get an error about an absent WSGI script or one that is unable to start. 

So I'm thinking that this is a problem with my WSGI (these subdomains point to Django projects). I'll try to fix it really quickly

Comment: I recommend you try to debug the VirtualHost config with simple sites configurations, then, when you are sure that Apache config is working, add whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the IP address to just port 80 in all instances:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName nmagerko.me
    ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This may help to solve an issue where the virtual host is listening for internal (local) traffic only. Since you're setting your domains A records, I'm assuming you're using a publicly available server?

Don't forget to reload apache after any conf file change:

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```

Lastly, let us know of this is just you testing locally. If it is, you likely don't need to change your domain's A record (unless you're hosting your own private DNS?).

Comment: Well I am using a server that I have at my residence. So it's just a single, private server. The problem is that I am setting an A record, but it is sending back the information for nmagerko.me instead of sub1.nmagerko.me

Answer (score 1):

Without the entire httpd.conf (including includes) it's impossible to tell from here, but adding

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
```

above your first `<virtualHost domain:80>` may help? Restart apache after the change.